# WebTileLayer can not show the map data in EPSG:3826 format

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I meet a problem when using WebTileLayer show the map data in EPSG:3826 format.

The code snippet is as following:

```
  const basemap = new Basemap({
                    baseLayers: [
                        new WebTileLayer({
                            urlTemplate: "https://wmts.nlsc.gov.tw/97/wmts/EMAP3826/default/default028mm/{level}/{row}/{col}",
                            title: "Basemap",
                            crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
                            extent: {
                                xmin: 128548.4443375419,
                                ymin: 2394066.4166165744,
                                xmax: 606875.5521,
                                ymax: 2919551.2968000006,
                                spatialReference: { wkid: 102443 }
                            },
                            spatialReference: { wkid: 102443 }
                        })
                    ],
                    title: "basemap",
                    id: "basemap",
                    spatialReference: { wkid: 102443 }
                });
```

And the error message shows:

> WebTileLayer .... spatialReference must match
> tileInfo.spatialReference.

Is there any other API methods can cover this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using WMTS layer service, you have to use ArcGIS `WMTSLayer` layer. Also with your `wkid` parameter you have to match layer CRS, which is `EPSG:3826`.

Relevant part of the code could then look something like this:

```
const basemap = new Basemap({
  baseLayers: [
    new WMTSLayer({
      url: "https://wmts.nlsc.gov.tw/97/wmts",
      activeLayer: { id:"EMAP3826", tileMatrixSetId: "default028mm" },
      serviceMode: "KVP",
      title: "Basemap",
      crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
      extent: {
        xmin: 128548.4443375419,
        ymin: 2394066.4166165744,
        xmax: 606875.5521,
        ymax: 2919551.2968000006,
        spatialReference: { wkid: 3826 }
      },
      spatialReference: { wkid: 3826 }
    })
  ],
  title: "basemap",
  id: "basemap",
  spatialReference: { wkid: 3826 }
});

var map = new Map({
  basemap: basemap
});

var view = new MapView({
  container: "divmap",
  map: map,
  zoom: 8,
  extent: {
    xmin: 296938.73458000005,
    ymin: 2776832.77203,
    xmax: 301876.2566600001,
    ymax: 2781271.34259,
    spatialReference: {
      wkid: 3826
    }
  },
  crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
  spatialReference: {
    wkid: 3826
  }
});
```

This is the result:

[image]